# can we import oracle 11g dump into 10g oracle database?

Tags: oracle

When i am trying to import i'm getting the error.can anyone help me?

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31637: cannot create job SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01 for user TBAADM
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT_INT", line 600
ORA-39080: failed to create queues "KUPC$C_1_20110614115239" and "KUPC$S_1_20110614115239" for data Pump job
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPC$QUE_INT", line 1555
ORA-00832: no streams pool created and cannot automatically create one
```

Comment: [Only if you specificed the lower `version` during export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#CEGFCFFI). Not sure if that's the cause if this error though. Does `TBAADM` have privileges for export/import? What was the full command used for the export, and what is the full command you're using for the import?

Answer (score 2):

yes you can. It does help to tell which expport/import tool you use, exp/imp or expdp/impdp. A simple google search reveals: [How to export from oracle 11.2 and import into 10.2 version](http://mohamedazar.com/2011/01/23/how-to-export-from-oracle-11-2-and-import-into-10-2-version/) This example is using both expdp/impdp and exp/imp.

The main difference is that when using expdp you need to specify the version of the database that is going to import the dump file. This is done on the commandline.

With exp, you need to use the exp utility from the lower version database.